# Bot Aiogram не правильно работает, помогите разобраться!

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Бот должен присылать мне уведомление если сегодняшняя дата есть в словаре, он присылает, но если даты нет мне нужно чтобы он уходил в сон на определённое время и при наступлении следующего дня, если даты совпадают присылать мне уведомление. Он выдает ошибку,  при этом продолжает работать и ничего не присылает...

```
    ######################### БОТ ##########################
from HappyBirthday import birthday
import config
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
import asyncio

bot = Bot(token=config.token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
delay = 2 #  24 часа в секундах



async def my_func():
    while True:
        try:
            await bot.send_message(config.myid, birthday())
        except:
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            
        when_to_call = loop.time(delay) # delay -- промежуток времени в секундах.
        loop.call_at(when_to_call, my_callback)

def my_callback():
    asyncio.ensure_future(my_func())

if __name__ =='__main__':
    my_callback()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<my_func() done, defined at Bot.py:17> exception=TypeError('time() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bot.py", line 24, in my_func
    when_to_call = loop.time(delay) # delay -- промежуток времени в секундах.
TypeError: time() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: у вас точно delay = 2 в коде ?

Comment: 2  в данный момент стоит просто для теста, чтобы долго не ждать. Вы об этом?